# Babel: use subset of stage-x preset plugins?

Tags: babeljs

How can I use two specific Babel plugins that are in a stage-x "preset", without having to use the entire preset?

Specifically, I want to use [`transform-class-properties`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and [`transform-decorators`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/) in my ES6 classes, both currently proposed for ES7 and part of the [stage-1](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/) preset.

Comment: Be aware, if you need decorators with Babel 6, you probably want `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`, not `babel-plugin-transform-decorators`

Comment: You should post your update as an answer and mark that as the accepted one. It's much more detailed than my existing answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @RGraham -- done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RGraham's answer was helpful--also wanted to share more details...

I'm using gulp, so first I had to upgrade from gulp-babel 5.x to 6.x:

  `npm install --save-dev babel/gulp-babel`

Then I needed to install ES2015 preset and the two plugins I want to use (+ the react preset since I'm using ReactJS):

```
  npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
  npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
  npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties 
  npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators
```

Last, I passed the following config to Babel (you could also specify this in your `.babelrc` file):

```
{
  presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
  plugins: [
    ["transform-class-properties"],
    ["transform-decorators"]
  ]
}
```

Your JavaScript linter will complain about the ES7 syntax. [This blog post](http://shellmonger.com/2015/08/21/adding-es7-class-properties-to-an-es6-react-component/) described the solution: modify lintjs to use Babel as the JavaScript parser. Set `"parser": "babel-eslint"` in your `.eslintrc` file then

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

Lastly for any other ReactJS folks, make sure you modify your component's constructor to include the props and context arguments or else you may get a runtime error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined`. Here's an example:

```
/**
   * ES6 constructor method (takes the place of the old React componentWillMount() method).
   * 
   * @param  {Object} props   See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html
   * @param  {Object} context See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html
   */
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    log.debug(`Creating ${this.constructor.name} instance`, props, context);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`presets` are just a collection of smaller `plugins`, so you can use that option to pull in the transforms you need:

*.babelrc (Or config)*

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "transform-decorators"]
}
```

Will give you all ES2015 + Class Properties + Decorators

Comment: Better to list the `transform-` plugins rather than the `syntax-` ones. Your suggestion will make them parse, but not transform them.

Comment: Can someone tell me what transform-class-properties does? I'd rather not create a new question for this, as I think it's not worth a big answer - but the NPM and github page don't make it clear.

Comment: @Elegant.Scripting Here's the proposal: https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties